# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":""}

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am making a bot to sign into discord and write some stuff, although when i sign in, there is a pop up message which i have to close(click the 'X' button) to go to my desired channel. But through my code, it is not closing the pop up message, it just says

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button"}
```

This is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import by
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import  time, os

class dankmemer_bot:
    def __init__(self):
        PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    
    def login(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get('https://discord.com/channels/@me/12345678901234567')
        gmail = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
        gmail.send_keys('example@gmail.com')
        password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
        password.send_keys(os.environ.get('password_example'))
        gmail.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    #The IMPORTANT part
    def close_tab(self):
        driver = self.driver
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button')
        button.click()
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver=10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button'))
            )
        except:
            driver.quit()

    def search_for_channel(self):
        driver = self.driver
        search_for_dankmemer = driver.find_element_by_class_name('searchBar-6Kv8R2')
        search_for_dankmemer.send_keys('dank-memer')

mybot = dankmemer_bot()    
mybot.login()
mybot.close_tab()
mybot.search_for_channel()
```

and this is the html:

```
<button aria-label="Close" type="button" class="closeButton-ryIVwg close-hZ94c6 button-38aScr lookBlank-3eh9lL colorBrand-3pXr91 grow-q77ONN"><div class="contents-18-Yxp"><svg class="closeIcon-150W3V" aria-hidden="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="currentColor" d="M18.4 4L12 10.4L5.6 4L4 5.6L10.4 12L4 18.4L5.6 20L12 13.6L18.4 20L20 18.4L13.6 12L20 5.6L18.4 4Z"></path></svg></div></button>
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the element

Comment: you want to click on button (after emal and password) to validate your account?

Comment: No its a pop up about some of their features(about student groups)

Comment: so its just a feature, i want to just close

Comment: i dont see what is this..if we cant reproduce it, it will be difficult to help you

Comment: anyways the message notify its not the right way, so your xpath is bad...open your inspect and see the xpath

Comment: Where in your code do you use the `//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button` xpath selector?

Answer (score 0):

To Close pop up or alert we can use this code

```
driver.switch_to_alert()
```

Then write the code to close the pop up

For example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
```